# Cannot start GWT development mode

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jetty, slf4j

I am using GWT SDK 2.8.1 and if I would like to start the GWT development mode I am getting the following stacktrace:

```
    Super Dev Mode starting up
   workDir: C:\Users\ss\AppData\Local\Temp\gwt-codeserver-7510213776616835391.tmp
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.slf4j.helpers.MessageFormatter.arrayFormat(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/slf4j/helpers/FormattingTuple;
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.log(JettyAwareLogger.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JettyAwareLogger.info(JettyAwareLogger.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.info(Slf4jLog.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.initialized(Log.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.MimeTypes.<clinit>(MimeTypes.java:168)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.WebServer.<clinit>(WebServer.java:90)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.SourceHandler.<clinit>(SourceHandler.java:63)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.loadModule(Recompiler.java:500)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.initWithoutPrecompile(Recompiler.java:204)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.maybePrecompile(Outbox.java:89)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.<init>(Outbox.java:61)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeOutboxTable(CodeServer.java:192)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:151)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:104)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:55)
```

Comment: What version of slf4j are you attempting to use?

Comment: I don't know which version of slf4j is used by the GWT plugin or the jetty. In my app I wouldn't need any logging...

Comment: I also tried to add the newest version of slfj to the build path of my project and the debugging configuration but without success

Comment: How can I configure the logging framework in GWT?

Comment: Do you have any kind of jetty jars as dependencies in your project, aside from the ones brought by GWT?

Comment: No, not that I am aware of. But I am also using the following jars on the build path: org.movieapps.gwt.highcharts-1.4.0.jar, smartgwt-skins.jar and smartgwt.jar (Version 3.0). I dont know if this libs have dependencies?

Comment: @Andrei: thank you for your help, you are right. I have found in own of my subproject a reference to an old version of slfj.jar. I have removed this jar from the build path of the subproject and now I can start the GWT development mode.